# shuffle image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, screen, shuffle

For instance, I have a screen size of 1024x768. And, each of my image is 150 x 250, where I have 4 images in total. How can i randomize these images to appear at different positions on the screen?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly?
Is it to:

- keep 4 predefined empty places and assign each of the 4 image to one empty place randomly,
- or simply place them randomly on the screen?

The idea is to display the images and keep the handle of each figure object (H1, H2, H3, H4). The ideal would be to store them in a handle list H.
For the first idea, store the top-left corner position of each empty place in a 4 entries list POS.
Make a connectivity list LC where LC[i]=j returns the index in POS where to find the position of the handle H[i].
For example, if LC = [1 2 3 4] handle H1 is assigned to position POS[1](http://mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html), H2 to POS[2], etc...
Then use randperm() ([mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html](http://mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randperm.html)) as Ashish pointed out on the LC list. This will randomly "mix" the connectivity list, and hence shuffle the positions.
Finally, set the position of each handle:

```
set(H[i], 'Position', [POS(LC[i],1) POS(LC[i],2) SizeX SizeY]);
```

Where SizeX and SizeY are the size ratios between the figure object and the screen.